# Plot a Graph in netlogo Using List

Tags: netlogo

I have list like this

list [[1 2 3 4][2 3 4 5][4 2 3 5]]

If it is possible to make such a graph. 
[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK6zI.jpg)
If not what is an alternate solution.

Comment: 1. As far as I know, you cannot put text on a NetLogo plot.  2. This is really a table, not a plot.  3. You could print the table text to an output area.  4. Other tools seem like a better choice (e.g., a spreadsheet).

Comment: Any example for the spreadsheet.